# Do Java Threads need any cleanup?

Tags: java, multithreading

I see that all the stop and destroy and anything else that deals with cleanup methods have been deprecated.

If I have a new Thread() or a class that extends Thread running, do I need to do anything in its run() method other than let it get to the end of regular execution? Or is there a background mechanism that understands that the Thread has run through all its tasks and can be destroyed?

Comment: Funniest part is that thread that might need a minor clean up is the one that has never been started.

Comment: @bestsss Care to expand on that in a response? :)

Comment: @pst, yeah - thread group, inheritedAccessControlContext, target, inherited thread locals&co remain untouched. Back in the day unstarted thread used to cause leaks in the ThreadGroup (it has been fixed, though). So if for some reason a reference is kept to such a thread, it can be a source of leaks. A lot of people leak stuff w/ shutdown hooks even w/o knowing.

Comment: `destroy()` is not merely deprecated, for all practical purposes it simply doesn't exist. If you try to call it, it won't stop the thread and it throws a `NoSuchMethodError`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you call `start()` on your thread, native mechanism in JVM close to the operating system are starting your thread, eventually executing `run()`. When `run()` finishes, JVM takes care of everything.

You might be concerned about garbage collection or other resources cleanup. Of course if you open file/network connection inside a thread, it must be closed like everywhere else. Also the garbage collector, while analyzing *live* objects, takes into account objects referred from running threads. But the moment thread finishes, all the objects referenced by it (or by `Runnable` implementation passed to the thread) are eligible for garbage collection.

quick&dirty edit for exit method of Thread, as visible contextClassLoader is missing x.x

```
private void exit() {
    if (group != null) {
        group.remove(this);
        group = null;
    }
    /* Aggressively null out all reference fields: see bug 4006245 */
    target = null;
    /* Speed the release of some of these resources */
    threadLocals = null;
    inheritableThreadLocals = null;
    inheritedAccessControlContext = null;
    blocker = null;
    uncaughtExceptionHandler = null;
}
```

Comment: *all the objects referenced by it (or by Runnable implementation passed to the thread) are eligible for garbage collection.* unfortunately so much NOT true at all. A dead thread keeps its reference to the contextClassLoader which could be a Huge issue.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for your comment, could you suggest me some resources that explain this issue in depth? I would like to edit my answer to be more relevant...

Comment: @Tomasz, The source code of java.lang.Thread, I always look at the source code. I did a quick look at your answers, quite well put and smart, I'd advise you to keep track and read the source code of JDK (java.lang/util as start). Then you know how the stuff works under the hood. You can never know better than see with your own eyes. Quick ref (I'll edit your answer to put the code of exit() method that cleans the stuff in Thread, you may not accept)

Comment: a dead thread keeps references to a lot of things. that's not an issue.

Comment: @irreputable, only the ccl now, it has been fixed to efficiently null the references for a reason.

Comment: bug 4006245 is from 1996, Java was 1 year old. Proactive nulling is not helpful to today's GC.

Comment: @irreputable, I didn't cite the bug itself. The null part is not to help the GC but to release references that thread didn't create on its own. Keeping references to dead threads has been source for leaks in jboss' tx manager - arjuna (for instance).

Answer (score 9):

No cleanup needed. Once it finishes its task, the jvm will kill it.

Comment: that's kinda what I thought but was having a hard time finding documentation that definitively spelled it out

Comment: It's the same thing when you run the main method of a simple java program. It does its thing and then it dies.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel, unless explicitly stated in java you need no clean-up.

Answer (score 1):

The stop() method actually causes the Thread to throw an Error or Exception.  The reason it is deprecated is this can happen anywhere in the code anything it modifies in a potentially unknown state. stop() is only really safe when stopping the current thread because you know when it will happen.  BTW, You can catch the Error/Exception which would mean the Thread does not stop().

In any case, the result is the same, the run() returns (or fails to catch an Exception/Error).  The stop() method triggers a special Error called ThreadDeath.  The only thing special about it is that normally, an uncaught exception/error is printed, but this one is not. (And it doesn't have Error at the end of its name ;) You can change this behaviour if you wish.

When the Thread is no longer referenced, it can be cleaned up. (just like any other object) Note: you can hold a reference to it in another thread, preventing it from being cleaned up even thought it has finished.

Comment: The reason given for deprecation of stop() isn't convincing. It's already the case that exceptions can occur any where in the code, and many of them are unexpected and uncaught. if a code is unsafe under stop(), it is unsafe without stop().

Comment: Broadly, I agree. Best not to use stop() if you can but if you have to, I think its better to use it than go to great lengths to avoid it.

Comment: the real reason, that they are shy to admit, is probably that stop() is not guaranteed to work, because ThreadDeath can be caught and ignored. I bet it doesn't work in majority of codes, people tend to catch Throwable in a lot of places.

Comment: @irreputable No. The reason `stop()` shouldn't be used is specifically that monitors held by the thread are instantly released, which doesn't happen during normal execution in correctly written code. It's all explained here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

Comment: quote: "The monitors are unlocked as the ThreadDeath exception propagates up the stack." That's true for any exception.

Comment: @irreputable, I treat ThreadDeath as OutOfMemoryError or StackOverFlowError (both are unpredictable). If the code can survive any of those, there is no reason it should have issues w/ ThreadDead. It's just difficult to code an application that can blow up at any point. But not so much: when you are the container that runs the application.

Comment: true, it is like manually triggering a StackOverFlowError on a thread. most synchronized blocks cannot really survive that with invariants unharmed. I guess it is acceptable that code is not safe under these errors. So it is better not to invoke stop().